# How to reload the updated custom UDF function in Hive?

Tags: hive, hive-udf

I wrote a custom UDF in java and packed in a `jar` file. Then, I added it in Hive using:

```
create temporary function isstopword as 'org.dennis.udf.IsStopWord';
```

Every thing worked fine. But, after I updated a small part in the UDF, I did the previous steps again, consequently Hive obviously still used old version UDF.

How can I refresh the updated version of UDF?

I tried to deleted the old `jar` file in hdfs, and drop the udf function with:

```
DROP TEMPORARY FUNCTION IF EXISTS isstopword;
```

Then recreate a new function with the same name, it still used the older version UDF.

Comment: Please mention the ADD jar statement that you are using

Comment: I use the Cloudera Management. so I upload the jar with Hue GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by following this document:http://bdlabs.edureka.co/static/help/topics/cm_mc_hive_udf.html#concept_zb2_rxr_lw_unique_1

Generally with the following steps:

1. added a config in hive-site.xml, then restart the hive server.

```
<property>
    <name>hive.reloadable.aux.jars.path</name>
    <value>/user/hive/udf</value>
</property>
```

2. deleted the old jar file in HDFS, and upload the new jar file.
3. `DROP TEMPORARY FUNCTION IF EXISTS isstopword;`
4. in hive console, run `list jar;` to check the local jar files, 
   it would print something like this:

```
/tmp/83ce8586-7311-4e97-813f-f2fbcec63a55_resources/isstopwordudf.jar
```

then delete them in your server file system.

5. create a temp function again.

```
create temporary function isstopword as 'org.dennis.udf.IsStopWord';
```

With the above steps, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

All the jars you add and the temporary functions you create are only specific to that particular hive session . Once you exit from that session all the temporary functions are lost forever .

Did you try closing the session and repeat the steps again .

Comment: I kept the same session. ok, I'll take a try.